# Unexpected curly brace in JSON

Tags: json, ruby

Opening curly brace became an unexpected token in Ruby
I used `json.parse` as well as `Yajl::Parser` and all of them get me to that point
JSON is valid, I checked it on several online validators
`Yajl::ParseError (lexical error: invalid char in json text.)
                                        {       "employees": [                  {
                     (right here) ------^`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):94
)SON::ParserError (765: unexpected token at '{
        "employees": [`

Comment: Can you upload the json and the rest of your code?

Comment: @nzajt I can't upload it due to security matters

Comment: Hint: Redact any identifiable information and give us the minimal version of your structure that's broken. If this is too secret to share, you're going to have to solve it on your own using tools [like this](https://jsonlint.com).

Comment: The structure is something like this `{"employees":[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]}`, but JSON is quite big. It is obtained via Net::FTP and when I try to read the file and then parse it I get this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in JSON file encoding which was generated on a Windows server, now it's solved

Comment: It would be great to mention how you solved the encoding error. Did you force an encoding on the string before passing it to Yajl?